# time spent on the highest-level task in Jira

Tags: jira, time-management, tracking

I'm asking for help with Jira.

The task is to track the time spent on the highest-level task and ideally do it by roles.
Now, let me explain in more detail how things currently stand.

The highest-level tasks are of the "Requirement" type.

Issues of the "Task" type are linked to them with the "is blocked by" relationship.
Sub-tasks are linked to the "Task" type as sub-tasks.

Developers usually track time for subtasks.

For Tasks, everything is fine - there is the total tracked time and a breakdown of time for Sub-tasks.

I would like to have the ability to see how much time has been spent in total on the highest-level task. Ideally, this time would be divided by roles, for example: 10 hours for front-end, 12 hours for back-end, 3 hours for QA.
[image]